# Cache-memory and C-functions

Tags: c, caching, nios

We have a function, strcpy, default optimization

```
 static void str_cpy( char *to, const char *from)
 {
      while( *from)
      {
            *to = *from;
            to = to + 1;
            from = from + 1;
      }
      *to = '\0';
  }
```

and another, matirsadd, high optimization (3)

```
 void matrisadd( int res[MATRIXSIZE_ROWS][MATRIXSIZE_COLS],
                 int  a[MATRIXSIZE_ROWS][MATRIXSIZE_COLS],
                 int b[MATRIXSIZE_ROWS][MATRIXSIZE_COLS] )
 {
     int i,j;
     for(j=0; j < MATRIXSIZE; ++j)
         for(i=0; i < MATRIXSIZE; ++i)
             res[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
 }
```

MATRIXSIZE (and w/e) = 16

With a cache size of 128 bytes, block size of 8 bytes and associativity of 1
Why does the first function get 86% hit-rate in the instruction cache while the matrisadd gets 99% hit-rate in the instruction cache?

EDIT:
We know that str_cpy makes up 18 assembly instructions per loop and that the cache has room for 32 instructions. So that would generate only the first "start-up"-misses untill we have loaded it into the cache and exploit time-locality. But matrisadd would have the same necessary start-up misses so, where does the extra misses come from in str_cpy?

Solution:
We solved it, had to do with the amount of loops each program had to take...

Comment: Is this homework? Where is your attempt at answering it, what have you done so far?

Comment: Won't answer to that if you don't justify that it's not homework, as @unwind says.

Comment: Like @unwind said, an attempt to answer it is pretty much the least you can provide.  You didn't even provide your thought process when looking at the question.  You should revisit the question, try it, then update your question accordingly.

Comment: This is not homework, it's an exploratory assignment to understand how cache-memory works and such. We've been trying to explain it by the amount of assembly instructions vs. the size of the cache but they should all fit as to our calculations. We've been stuck on this for a couple of days now...